# Append data into Table Variable using bulk collect

Tags: database, oracle, rdbms

I'm trying to append data into table variable. But this approach is overwriting the data. And, I'm getting the value generated at **i=50**. Is there any approach I can use to append data within for loop. Kindly help

```
TYPE employee_info_t IS TABLE OF enrolcols; 
 l_enro   employee_info_t:=employee_info_t();

FOR i IN 40..50
    LOOP
select   i+1,id + i ,
         0,
         'T',
         '08',
         0,
         00,
         '08',
         'PAS',
         'BULK',
         'BULKLOAD',
         system_timestamp,
         system_timestamp   bulk collect into l_enro from dual;
end loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need use bulk collect statment here. Use bulk collect when loading collections from a sql. 
If i undestand your code you want to populate collection in plsql.  Try something similar to this.

```
TYPE employee_info_t IS TABLE OF enrolcols; 
 l_enro   employee_info_t:=employee_info_t();
FOR i IN 40..50
    LOOP
    l_enro.extend(1);
    l_enro(l_enro.COUNT) := enrolcols(i+1,id + i ,
                             0,
                             'T',
                             '08',
                             0,
                             00,
                             '08',
                             'PAS',
                             'BULK',
                             'BULKLOAD',
                             system_timestamp,
                             system_timestamp);
end loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without the loop using a hierarchical query:

```
select enrolcols(
         LEVEL+40,
         id + 39 + LEVEL,
         0,
         'T',
         '08',
         0,
         00,
         '08',
         'PAS',
         'BULK',
         'BULKLOAD',
         system_timestamp,
         system_timestamp
       )
bulk collect into l_enro
from dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 11;
```

Comment: @Tans updated for a typo and needed to wrap with the object type.

Comment: enrolcols is a record. So l_enro not accepting Level+40. The column mapped on this location is of number type.